# Is there a way I can use use a authentication attribute used in controller for JWT authentication for a middleware method?

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-middleware

I currently have auth on controller class like

[AuthenticateJWT]
Public class controller......

And it authenticates every http request's JWT for the routes of this controller class

I want to validate JWT tokens in a middleware method.

How can I do that?

Comment: Hi @fozail akram,What is your scenario? Why you want to validate the jwt token in middleware? By default you just need configure `AddAuthentication` and `AddJwtBearer` middleware, then use `[Authorize]` attribute.

Comment: Hey @rena, I'm using graphql middleware and want to authenticate requests before it reaches the middleware by adding my own middleware in between.

Comment: Hi @fozail akram, how do you invoke the middelware. The middelware registered in startup runs with the order. You can invoke the grapgql middleware after app.UseAuthentication().

Comment: That helped thanks!
Added a TokenValidator middleware.